# Coldfusion FTP error: Algorithm negotiation fail

Tags: algorithm, coldfusion, cfftp

I'm trying to open a cfftp connection, but it is returning error 82 (Algorithm negotiation fail)

My connection:

```
<cfftp  action = "open"
    connection = "MyConnection"
    username = "xxxxx"
    password = "xxxxx"
    server = "207.59.193.220"
    secure = "yes"
    stopOnError = "No">

<cfdump var = '#cfftp#' />
```

It returns the error:   82 Algorithm negotiation fail

Does anyone know why it is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the certificate installed on your ColdFusion server? In the correct java keystore that ColdFusion is running under.

Comment: Which certificate?

Comment: The SSL certificate of the server that you are attempting to connect and ftp files to.